# Android Jetpack Compose NavHost

Tags: android, compose, jetpack

всем привет. Вопрос такой я открываю Activiy

```
    Scaffold ( ){
           NavHost (navController =c, startDestination ="R1"){
                composable ("R1"){
                   println ("run R1")
               }
               composable ("R2"){
                  println ("run R2")
               } 
          }
   }
```

я получаю при вызове c.navigate ("R2")

run R1
run R2
run R1
run R2
run R2

Comment: а как объявили ваш `с`, покажите

Comment: c= rememberNavController( )